# How do I create a Purchase with a Vendor and Date? (Is this what I want to do?) - Quickbooks API

Tags: quickbooks

I am adding an integration to Quickbooks. This integration is going to export purchase transactions from my app to Quickbooks.

When I look at the Quickbooks [API Explorer](https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/api/accounting/all-entities/purchase) I see the Purchase object, but the request body for CREATE doesn't have much of the information I would expect it to have, like Merchant, Date, or Memo.

If I go this route, it appears that I have to create a Purchase, then do an update with the other information I would want to add to the Purchase.

I feel like I must be doing something wrong. Is there a better way to do this? Should I use something other that a "Purchase" to achieve the result that I want? Or should I just use the Purchase and then update it after?

Also, I am looking at the official docs. Is there a better place to get answers with better examples?